# I want to vertically align image with the text in the table

Tags: tables, align

I want to vertically align image with the text in the table. Text begins after the image and is on the down side.The code I have been using is

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{p{3in} r}
     \includegraphics[height=3cm, valign=m]{logo.jpg}  & univname \\
       & deptname \\
       & Center for Advanced Studies in Chemistry\\
       & facname, placeln \\
       & Tel:  \\
       \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the valign option that is available  when adding \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} to the preamble.

Comment: Why do you use tabularx here? Since you don't have a X type column, a regular tabular is sufficient.

Comment: Alternatively you could also use two side by side minipages. One for the image and the second for a single column table.

Comment: You haven't stated how `\btypeout`, `\univname`, `\deptname`, `\facname`, or `\placesh` are defined, and you haven't provided access to `logo.jpg`. What exactly are you asking us to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Please in question always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document beggining with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}, which reproduce your problem
- used document class is unknown
- In your code fragment is not defined commands `\univname`, `\deptname`, `\facname` and `\placesh`
- in `tabularx` table at least one column had to be `X` type

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XL}
\multirow{7.4}{=}{\includegraphics[height=3cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}}    %{Pictures/logo.jpg}} 
            & University name  \\
            & Department name \\
            & Center for advanced Studies in Chemistry \\
            & Faculty pretty long name in two columns\\
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

*Note*: With `valign` you can move baseline of image to the top (options `T` or `t`) of image, (vertical) middle (options `M`or`m`) or to bottom (options `B` or `b`). For details see package documentation, subsection *4.6 Vertical Alignment*, page 24.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to provide MWE. \univname, \deptname, \facname and \placesh corresponds to University name, department name , faculty name and local place name respectively. Thank you for the  solution, however it didn't solved my problem you. I tried \valign=m but the text in two rows, in the next column,  gets split. Please tell me any details you require

Comment: @Harsh you can make an example as Zarko has done, You do not need those commands for university name, replace by any text `University` `Faculty` or whatever words you want, and use `example-image` as the image, the important thing is that you post a complete document that other people can run and shows the problem.

Comment: @David Carlisle I replaced University, faculty etc  but that's not the problem,  My image in 1 Column, splits my text between two adjacent rows in the next column, even after applying the provided solution. I also changed \tabularx to \tabular.

Comment: @Harsh it is not a problem for _you_ but it is a problem for everybody else as no one can run your example or see the problem that you are asking about. See the example in Zarko's answer, anybody can run that and test it works on their system. No one, not even you, can run the example as posted in your question. You need to edit your question to show the problem otherwise no one will know what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well can you guide me how to do that? Shall I copy, paste my entire code beginning from documentclass?

Comment: @Harsh no basically start from the code in zarko's answer and edit it so that it shows the problem you are having then add that to your question, we really don't need to see your entire thesis and load dozens of packages unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your support the solution provided by Zarko works but how can I increase cell width in the same solution?.

Comment: @Harsh change X in the first column to `l`  then the first col will be as wide as the image, and all remaining space goes to the text column